# Find the relation between length of pulley and strings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, geometry, relative-motion

> A pulley is pulled with external force $F$. $x$ and $y$ denote the displacement of two ends of strings of the pulley and $z$ is the displacement of the pulley.
>
> **Prove That** $$z = \dfrac{x+y}{2}$$
>
> [image]

My teacher stated it in class without providing a proof. I think that it is valid for ideal conditions (massless pulley and string) and only with certain kinds of forces, but he says it is valid in all cases.

Can anyone help me with the general proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Care to elaborate?

Comment: The only condition you need for the validity of the relation is that the string is inextensible. I suggest you to start looking at particular cases. For example, if z=0 it should be x=-y. And if x=y then z=x=y.

Comment: Hi Henry and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let l is length of string.
m is length of pulley string.
h is height of system.
k is height of  pulley after it is raised.

$h = m+ \frac{l}{2} \tag{1} $

$k = \frac{l+x+y}{2} \tag{2} $

$ h+ z = m +k $

From (2)
$h+z = m+ \frac{l+x+y}{2} $

From (1)
$ m+ \frac{l}{2} +z = m+ \frac{l+x+y}{2} $

On Solving

$z=\frac{x+y}{2}$

Comment: I am deleting this in keeping with [our policy on complete answer to homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). Flag a mod in a couple of weeks to have it un-deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the string is fixed (i.e. if the string is inextensible), then we have:

($l$ is the length of the string)
[image]

$$l=(s_1-s_3)+(s_1-s_5)+\pi R=2s_1-s_3-s_5+\pi R$$
$$l=(s_2-s_4)+(s_2-s_6)+\pi R=2s_2-s_4-s_6+\pi R$$
$$z=s_2-s_1\quad x=s_4-s_3\quad y=s_6-s_5$$
$$\Longrightarrow\; 2s_2-2s_1=(s_4-s_3)+(s_6-s_5)$$
$$\Longrightarrow\; 2z=x+y$$

Comment: I am deleting this in keeping with [our policy on complete answer to homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). Flag a mod in a couple of weeks to have it un-deleted.